# Injection in a referenced class library?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, code-injection

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 website that references a class library(DAL). To access the connectionstring from the appsettings.json(ASP.NET project) I need inject the configuration somehow. I have created a class in the class Library that looks like this :

```
    public class Helper
{
    IConfiguration Configuration;
    public Helper(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public string GetConnectionString(string name)
    {
        return Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    }
}
```

The injection pattern do however not pick this up so it demands a IConfigration to create the class.

How do I access the appsettings.json from the class library?

Comment: Share us how you will initialize and use `Helper` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class library should not know or care how you're handling configuration in your app. All your `Helper` class needs is a connection string, so that is what you should inject into it. *How* that string is provided is an implementation detail that's part of your application domain.

```
public class Helper
{
     public Helper(string connectionString)
     {
          // do something with connectionString
     }
}
```

Then, in your app:

```
services.AddScoped(p =>
    new Helper(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Thansk, looks great, but how do I instantiate the Helper class? it still wants the connectionstring as inparameter?

Comment: It's there in the answer above. You're adding the helper as a scoped service and telling it exactly how to create it with the action, i.e. get the connection string from config and pass it into the constructor. All you do now is just inject your helper where you need it. The DI container takes care of the rest.

Comment: Sorry, but I do still not get it, If I add the Helper as inparameter to my Factory class this factory class will complain if I do not provide the helper manually on instantiation.

When I worked with injections before I only hade to register that ISomeInterface is  SomeClassWithISomeInterface and then when adding ISometInterface to the constructor as inparameter it has been generated as told in the injection registration.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening here. The AddScoped registers your helper class in the service collection, whenever something else like your factory needs that helper, it will inject that instance.